# SELECT timestamp from SQL query in python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

```
cur.execute('Select ts from testtable where nd_a>%s and nd_b>%s and nd_c>%s',(medA,medB,medC))
result_ts=cur.fetchall()
print (result_ts)
```

when i get the output this is look like this:

```
((datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 15, 24),), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 15, 38),), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 16, 30),), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 16, 37),), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 17, 8),), (datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 17, 14),))
```

When I need the output date in this format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

How I change it to this format view?

Comment: You need to print the values: `print (result_ts[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```py
cur.execute('Select ts from testtable where nd_a>%s and nd_b>%s and nd_c>%s',(medA,medB,medC))
result_ts=cur.fetchall()

for result in result_ts:
    print(result[0])
```

This will print:

```
2020-01-01 01:15:24
2020-01-01 01:15:38
2020-01-01 01:16:30
2020-01-01 01:16:37
2020-01-01 01:17:08
2020-01-01 01:17:14
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a string timestamp, you should use the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method.

```
cur.execute('Select ts from testtable where nd_a>%s and nd_b>%s and nd_c>%s',(medA,medB,medC))
result_ts=cur.fetchall()
timestamps = []
for r in results_ts:
    timestamps.append(r[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s'))
```

This will give you a list of results translated into timestamp strings :)

Comment: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s is the default format. There's no point using of using strftime!

Comment: Depends on what they want to do with it - if they just want to print it, `print()` is good, but if they hope to use it for something then strftime might be helpful :)